# Joomla+Virtuemart blank page with no errors

Tags: joomla3.0

I am using Joomla version 3.4.0 and virtuemart version 3.0.6.2, frequently i am getting blank page with 500 internal server error. I turned on php error reporting then also i didn't get any errors on the screen and also turned on Error reporting to maximum in joomla global configuration i didn't get any errors.Please do help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. "500 internal server" error means that is a server error... check the cpanel php error log and check the reason. Sometimes it is folder permission issues. Set the administrator folder to 655...
2. Disable plugins that are newly installed... and keep disabling other plugins till u get some text on the frontend
3. I had a similar issue...i checked the browser "view source"..and it did show some html code. and for some reason the body was set in css to "display: none".
4. add this line to index.php and the administrator/index.php 
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
5. change the template and check the output.